# TIdTCPClient start TLS after connected

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I'm dealing with a protocol that needs to start TLS after connected and handshaked, something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  SSL:= TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
  SSL.SSLOptions.Method:= sslvTLSv1_2;
  IdTCPClient1.Connect;
  if IdTCPClient1.Connected then
  begin
    //plain-text operations
    HandShake;
    CheckAnswer;
    //finish plain-text start TLS
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler:= SSL;
    SendTLSSecureBytes;
  end;
end;
```

Once I get inside SendTLSSecureBytes procedure, and send something over the connection, I get the exception: "Connection closed gracefully"

Something missing to do this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the `SSLIOHandler` object to the `TIdTCPClient.IOHandler` property *before* you call `TIdTCPClient.Connect()`.  If you do not assign an `IOHandler` object, `Connect()` will create a default TCP-only object, and you can't assign a new `IOHandler` object once the socket connection has been opened.

Then, set the `SSLIOHandler.PassThrough` property to False when you are ready to invoke the TLS handshake:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdTCPClient1);
  SSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
  IdTCPClient1.Connect; // raises exception if failed
  // do plain-text operations, then...
  SSL.PassThrough := False // do TLS handshake
  SendTLSSecureBytes; // will be encrypted by TLS
end;
```

Note, for future reference (not applicable to this situation), if you need the TLS handshake to be performed immediately upon establishing the socket connection, you can set the `SSLIOHandler.PassThrough` property to False before calling `TIdTCPClient.Connect()`, and the handshake will be completed before `Connect()` exits:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdTCPClient1);
  SSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
  SSL.PassThrough := False // do TLS handshake upon connect
  IdTCPClient1.Connect; // raises exception if failed
  SendTLSSecureBytes; // will be encrypted by TLS
end;
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!