# Start TLS after connection has been established in TIdCmdTcpServer

Tags: delphi, indy

We are using a `TIdCmdTCPServer` with a `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` server-side and `TIdTCPClient` with `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` client-side in Delphi 10.1.

I can successfully establish an encrypted connection when setting PassThrough to false before calling `FTCPClient.Connect` and having

```
procedure TIndyTcpCommandReceiver.TCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  if AContext.Connection.IOHandler is TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL then
    TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(AContext.Connection.IOHandler).PassThrough := false;
end;
```

We deploy the same server.exe to various servers. Some of them have certificates installed, others don't.

**I only want to establish an encrypted connection, if there is a certificate.**

I modified my client side code following the instructions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412958/865602, initially setting `PassThrough := true` and setting `PassThrough := false` once a connection has been established.

```
procedure TTCPConnector.Connect;
begin
  FSSLIOHandler.PassThrough := true;
  FTCPClient.Connect(FServerName, FPort); // succeeds
  FSSLIOHandler.PassThrough := false ; // fails
end;
```

However, I can't find an answer on how to modify my server-side code. I can only establish the initial connection if I don't use the code in the `TCPServerConnect` event.

**What do I have to change in the server to switch to an encrypted connection after the client set PassThrough to false?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I only want to establish an encrypted connection, if there is a certificate.

Then you need to change your protocol to a STARTTLS model, where the client asks the server for permission to encrypt the connection before actually doing so.

Have the client connect normally with `PassThrough=True` on both sides. Then have the client send an unencrypted command to the server, and have the server respond with whether permission is granted or denied based on whether a certificate is installed. If granted, then both parties can set `PassThrough=False` to encrypt the connection before any further data is exchanged.

For example:

```
procedure TIndyTcpCommandReceiver.TCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  if AContext.Connection.IOHandler is TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase then
    TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(AContext.Connection.IOHandler).PassThrough := true;
end;

procedure TIndyTcpCommandReceiver.TCPServerSTARTTLSCommand(ASender: TIdCommand);
begin
  if (ASender.Context.Connection.IOHandler is TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase) and
     TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(ASender.Context.Connection.IOHandler).PassThrough and
     (Certificate Is Installed) then // <-- implement as needed...
  begin
    ASender.Reply.SetReply(220, 'Send TLS handshake');
    ASender.SendReply;
    TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(ASender.Context.Connection.IOHandler).PassThrough := False;
  end
  else
    ASender.Reply.SetReply(454, 'Dont send TLS handshake');
end;
```

```
procedure TTCPConnector.Connect;
begin
  FSSLIOHandler.PassThrough := true;
  FTCPClient.Connect(FServerName, FPort);
  FTCPClient.GetResponse; // read greeting if needed
  if FTCPClient.SendCmd('STARTTLS') = 220 then
    FSSLIOHandler.PassThrough := false;
end;
```

Comment: I guess it should be `ASender.Context.Connection.IOHandler` instead of `AContext.Connection.IOHandler`

Comment: I still can't get this to work properly. First, `SetReply(', 'Send TLS handshake');` raises an `EIdException` with `RSReplyInvalidCode`. I changed the response code to 700 (which is in the range defined in `TIdReplyRFC.CheckIfCodeIsValid`. 

On the client-side I get a '200 Welcome' response.

Comment: Furthermore, the client throws this exception: EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError: Fehler beim Verbinden mit SSL.
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol.

The server throws this exception: EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message 'Fehler beim Annehmen der Verbindung mit SSL.
error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version'.

I am using `FSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2]`.

Comment: @christian thanks for the `IOHandler` correction. Your client gets the `200 Welcome` because your server has a `Greeting` assigned that your client is not reading after `Connect()`. You need to either disable the `Greeting` on the server, or else have the client read it, ie with `GetResponse()`

Comment: thanks for your help. I've updated the implementation as per your instructions and it worked like a charm.